# How do i find and fix the true cause of page life expectancy issues?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

We have been having performance problems on our sql server the last month, and we have a hard time getting it fixed.

This was the page life expectancy of one full week, one year ago:

[image: Page life expectancy of one week, last year]

You see that we have frequent dips in the morning, but thats when our heavy batch processes kick in. During the day everything is peachy.

The same graph, but the current situation:

[image]

Big difference, lots of user complaints.

A detail of the day:

[image]

We have 64Gb of ram in the server, which should be plenty. Normally when we have performance issues, we start looking at the queries that cause the most total wait time (we have an analysis tool or that), we try to improve/remove/cache these queries and usually this simply works.

In this case, i have been following the same approach, but it does not seem to affect the PLE counters. How can i correctly identity the cause of these problems so i can fix what needs to be fixed?

Comment: I don't want to teach you to suck eggs but have you tried running sp_Blitz and sp_BlitzCache from the Brent Ozar First Responder Kit? https://www.brentozar.com/responder/ . Also, how much data in your database?

Comment: another link [Fixing Page Life Expectancy (PLE)](https://simplesqlserver.com/2013/08/19/fixing-page-life-expectancy-ple/)

Comment: Sizes of databases on the instance? What was it 1 year ago? Data access pattern?

Comment: One database of 170Gb. Last year it was smaller than 100Gb. Data access patterns is a very mixed bag: lots of simultaneous small transaction and read, but also large queries coming from backend tools

Comment: You can do a sql trace (1 hour) and then import result into a table and do a select with order by Reads desc  to show queries that reads lot of pages